# How can I link Google maps API to C# Window form App

Tags: javascript, c#, api

I'm working on C# to display Maps and traffics with google maps API not GMap How can  I link Google's map API from the HTML page to my C# program?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/889136/Csharp-Google-Maps-in-WinForm-with-WebBrowser-and this link might have some details on where to get started. I think you probably want to use a `WebView` control.